# LEFT JOIN four tables with unwanted result

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I made a little projects manager. I need to know how many open projects are assigned to users of a particular user group.

I created four tables:

**users**

```
╔════╦══════════╦══════════════╗
║ id ║ group_id ║ full_name    ║
╠════╬══════════╬══════════════╣
║  1 ║     4    ║ Jescie Head  ║
╠════╬══════════╬══════════════╣
║  2 ║     1    ║ Amity Mooney ║
╠════╬══════════╬══════════════╣
║  3 ║     1    ║ Ivy Yates    ║
╠════╬══════════╬══════════════╣
║  4 ║     1    ║ Bo Goff      ║
╚════╩══════════╩══════════════╝
```

**projects**

```
╔════╦══════╦════════╗
║ id ║ code ║ status ║
╠════╬══════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ P001 ║    0   ║
╠════╬══════╬════════╣
║  2 ║ P002 ║    1   ║
╚════╩══════╩════════╝
```

**groups**

```
╔════╦══════╦═════════╦════════╗
║ id ║ type ║ name    ║ status ║
╠════╬══════╬═════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║   0  ║ Group 1 ║    1   ║
╠════╬══════╬═════════╬════════╣
║  2 ║   2  ║ Group 2 ║    1   ║
╠════╬══════╬═════════╬════════╣
║  4 ║   1  ║ Group 4 ║    1   ║
╚════╩══════╩═════════╩════════╝
```

**project_user**

```
╔═════════╦════════════╗
║ id_user ║ id_project ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║    5    ║      2     ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║    4    ║      2     ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║    3    ║      2     ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║    4    ║      1     ║
╚═════════╩════════════╝
```

I wish to find how many active project are assigned to the user of group 1 (type 0). My query works, show the right users but counts also the project with status 0:

```
SELECT u.id, 
       u.full_name, 
       u.type, 
       Count(pu.id_project) AS assigned_projects 
FROM   users AS u 
       LEFT JOIN project_user AS pu 
              ON u.id = pu.id_user 
       JOIN groups AS g 
         ON g.id = u.group_id 
            AND g.type = 0 
       LEFT JOIN projects AS p 
              ON pu.id_project = p.id 
                 AND p.status = 1 
GROUP  BY u.id 
ORDER  BY u.type, u.id ASC
```

**UPDATE**

**Current result:**

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════╦═══════════════════╗
║ id ║   full_name  ║ type ║ assigned_projects ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╬═══════════════════╣
║  2 ║ Amity Mooney ║   3  ║         0         ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╬═══════════════════╣
║  3 ║   Ivy Yates  ║   6  ║         1         ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╬═══════════════════╣
║  4 ║    Bo Goff   ║   1  ║         2         ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╩═══════════════════╝
```

**Wanted result:** Cause project 2 is closed.

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════╦═══════════════════╗
║ id ║   full_name  ║ type ║ assigned_projects ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╬═══════════════════╣
║  2 ║ Amity Mooney ║   3  ║         0         ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╬═══════════════════╣
║  3 ║   Ivy Yates  ║   6  ║         0         ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╬═══════════════════╣
║  4 ║    Bo Goff   ║   1  ║         1         ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╩═══════════════════╝
```

**DB Fiddle:** [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=HljVmrBDhK)

Comment: "My query works, show the right users but counts also the project with status 0:" it "works" (in quotes) yes but will generate invalid data because you use GROUP BY wrong unless MySQL could have used functional dependency to get the correct data.. What results do you expected?

Comment: @RaymondNijland I updated with expected result.

Comment: You expected result is not coherent with your data sample  .. "Bo Goff" ???

Comment: @scaisEdge sorry, wrong copy/paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't use left join while connecting the "projects" table. In addition, your group by line should be fixed. Please try the query below.

```
SELECT u.id,u.full_name,u.type,Count(pu.id_project) AS assigned_projects 
FROM users AS u 
JOIN groups AS g ON g.id = u.group_id AND g.type = 0 
LEFT JOIN project_user AS pu ON u.id = pu.id_user 
JOIN projects AS p ON pu.id_project = p.id AND p.status = 1 
GROUP BY u.id,u.full_name,u.type
ORDER  BY u.type, u.id ASC
```

EDIT: If you want to see all the users, even though there is no assigned active project for that user, than you need to use below (SUM with case-when instead of COUNT and remove status check in join line):

```
SELECT u.id,u.full_name,u.type,SUM(CASE WHEN p.status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS assigned_projects 
FROM users AS u 
JOIN groups AS g ON g.id = u.group_id AND g.type = 0 
LEFT JOIN project_user AS pu ON u.id = pu.id_user 
JOIN projects AS p ON pu.id_project = p.id
GROUP BY u.id,u.full_name,u.type
ORDER  BY u.type, u.id ASC
```

EDIT 2: Here the example data prepared in MSSQL. You will need to remove # symbols for mysql.

```
create table #users (id int, groupid int, fullname varchar(50))
create table #groups (id int, [type] int, name varchar(50),[status] bit)
create table #projects (id int, code varchar(50), [status] bit)
create table #project_user (id_user int , id_project int)

insert into #users values (1,4,'Jescie'),(2,1,'Amity'),(3,1,'Ivy'),(4,1,'Jesse')
insert into #projects values (1,'p001',0),(2,'p002',1)
insert into #groups values (1,0,'G1',1),(2,2,'G2',1),(4,1,'G4',1)
insert into #project_user values (5,2),(4,2),(3,2),(4,1)

SELECT u.id,u.fullname,g.[type], SUM(CASE WHEN p.status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS assigned_projects 
FROM #users AS u 
JOIN #groups AS g ON g.id = u.groupid AND g.type = 0 
LEFT JOIN #project_user AS pu ON u.id = pu.id_user 
LEFT JOIN #projects AS p ON pu.id_project = p.id 
GROUP BY u.id,u.fullname,g.[type]
ORDER  BY g.[type], u.id ASC
```

[image]

Comment: This way works for projects, but doesn't show users without projects assigned.

Comment: @WalterV do you want to see all the users in your result set, or only group 1 users?

Comment: All users of group 1 with the numer of asssigned projects. Also 0. Read my update.

Comment: Thanks ErayBalkanli but same result. Doesn't show user with no projects.

Comment: @WalterV I am sure it will work, I tested it. Please try to copy paste and run again. Here I added some example data and my result set

Comment: I changed syntax into MySQL and finally works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am glad to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186370/discussion-between-walterv-and-eray-balkanli).